# How can we include app check tokens in sending Firestore REST Api requests?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I've created a custom Firebase App Check provider for my firebase apps. My question is, how do I properly send a successful request using Firestore REST API after getting the token from my custom app check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appCheck token in the headers of your request like so

```
// Include the App Check token with requests to your server.
  const apiResponse = await fetch('https://yourFirebaseRestApiURL/Endpoint', {
      headers: {
          'X-Firebase-AppCheck': appCheckTokenResponse.token,
      }
  });
```

This is not documented in the Firestore Rest API but in the AppCheck docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/custom-resource